# How can I write tests for my smart contracts?

Tags: smart-contracts, testing

I like doing TDD and would like to build up a test suite around my contract code. I have been looking at both ReasonML and Liquidity but neither seems to have a great testing story yet. Does it make sense going full OCaml instead?

What are people using?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several test frameworks coming for Tezos. Ours (Techelson) can be used both from Michelson and from Liquidity. It should be released soon.

(I will update this answer when it is released)

Comment: Here it is https://github.com/OCamlPro/techelson, see the doc here http://techelson.ocamlpro.com/doc/

Answer (score 4):

Tezos environment manager has a contract testing framework planned on the roadmap, you can check the current status [at this git repo](https://github.com/maht0rz/tezos-environment-manager).

Answer (score 0):

[cleveland](https://gitlab.com/morley-framework/morley/-/blob/9455cd384b2ab897fb7b31822abca3730a4ad08b/code/cleveland/testingEDSL.md) is a test framework for Michelson contracts. It takes advantage of Haskell's already existing testing tools: [QuickCheck](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck), [hspec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hspec) and [hedgehog](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hedgehog). It allows you to test contracts written in the low level eDSL [lorentz](https://gitlab.com/morley-framework/morley/-/tree/master/code/lorentz), the high level eDSL [indigo](https://gitlab.com/morley-framework/indigo), hand written Michelson contracts or Michelon output by any other programming language such as [SmartPy](https://smartpy.io/) or [LIGO](https://ligolang.org/).

SmartPy also supports unit tests with their [test scenarios](https://smartpy-io.medium.com/introducing-test-scenarios-in-smartpy-io-fae1d3ee56ea).